# Commands are not executed after switching user in Fabric python

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I came across an issue that commands are not executed after switching a user on a remote server using `run` operation.

Things I wanted to do:

1. connect to remote host
2. switch to userB
3. run a script under userB

Code snippet:

```
env.hosts = ['userA@hello.com']
def build():
    run("sudo su - userB")
    run("./path/to/run.sh")   #<----- this line is not executed
```

When running the python script, the standout I got is:

> [userA@hello.com] Executing task 'build'
>
> [userA@hello.com] run: sudo su - userB
>
> [userA@hello.com] Login password for 'userA':
>
> [userA@hello.com] out: [sudo] password for userA:
>
> [userA@hello.com] out: [userB@hello.com ~]$

PS: I could type in the password for Login and sudo.

Answer (score 0):

The context of every fabric command is independent to each other. So your `run("./path/to/run.sh")` is still being called by userA.

You need to share the environment context with `with`:

```
def build():
  with settings(user='userB',password='foobar'):
    run("./path/to/run.sh")
```

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings

Comment: It's to no avail. I got `/bin/bash: ./path/to/run.sh: Permission denied`. It seems that it failed to `sudo su - userB` somehow.